# Rspec-view-file doesn't know about my routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm new in rspec, write rspec-test for `View` and there's a problem:
test fails with error:

```
 Failure/Error: render
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"create", :format=>nil}
```

model's relations are simple:

```
post has_many :comments
comment belongs_to :post
```

view file:

```
# app/views/posts/show.html.haml

#postform
  = form_for @comment do |f|
    = f.text_field :name
    = f.submit "Reply"
```

rspec file:

```
# spec/views/posts/show.html.haml_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'posts/show.html.haml' do
  it 'renders the form for a new comment creation' do
    assign(:post, mock_model(Post).as_new_record.as_null_object)
    assign(:comment, mock_model(Comment).as_new_record.as_null_object) 
    render
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  post '/:name/comments' => 'comments#create', :as => :comments
```

Application works normal. But if I remove that line from routes.rb, then in development mode I getting same error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"create", :format=>nil}
```

So I think it looks like rspec-view-file doesn't know about my routing, but I'm not sure. Anyway, how can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rspec view testing do know your routes, so imho something else is wrong. When looking at your route, I see a parameter `:name`.

Shouldn't you be specifying `:name` somehow? It seems like it should be pointing to the parent-post, no?
So not quite sure how this could work.

It seems you want to be doing something like

```
= form_for [@post, @comment]
```

or build the url explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for reply! The problem was exactly with `:name` parameter. I've  assigned `post` mock-model with parameters, added this line in `rspec` file: `controller.request.path_parameters[:name] = post.name` and test works properly now.